# найти средний элемент односвязного списка за один проход

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Как найти средний элемент односвязного списка за один проход?

Comment: Подозреваю что без использования дополнительной памяти - никак.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод двух бегунков. Один медленный, за шаг прохода прыгает на следующий узел. Один быстрый, за шаг прохода прыгает на 2 узла. Когда быстрый добежит до конца списка, медленный окажется в его середине.

Например, если узел списка выглядит как

```
public class ListNode
{
    public int val;
    public ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

Тогда поиск середины будет выглядеть

```
public ListNode MiddleNode(ListNode head)
{
    var slow = head;
    var fast = head;        
    while(fast!=null && fast.next!=null)
    {
        fast = fast.next.next;                      
        slow = slow.next;
    }       
    return slow;        
}
```

Проверить корректность можно [здесь](https://leetcode.com/problems/middle-of-the-linked-list/)

Comment: Но ведь это за 2 прохода, а не за 1. Чем это лучше, чем посчитать за первый проход число элементов, а за второй дойти до среднего? Кстати, у меня ещё есть сомнения по корректности работы приведённого алгоритма при различных длинах.

Comment: @Qwertiy что по вашему есть проход? Например, если я бы скопировал связанный список в List  и потом просто вернул середину листа - это один проход? Где я проверял корректность я указал. Если знаете контрпримеры, приведите, я поправлю код.

Comment: Один поход - это когда только один итератор создаётся. Да, копирование в list - это один проход, но с использованием дополнительной памяти, но об этом в вопросе ничего не говорится. У меня была такая же идея, но это слишком просто и подозрительно.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не создаю итераторов, значит у меня ноль проходов? К тому же у меня второй бегунок до конца не дойдет, у меня 1.5 прохода?  :) Копирование в лист тоже требует перечисление элементов, это считается за проход?

Comment: Я понимаю один проход так: есть нечто IEnumerable<T> и с него можно не более одного раза получить енумератор, которым можно дойти до конца (или не до конца), но возвращаться назад или создавать ещё один енумератор нельзя. У тебя их два - быстрый и медленный. Причём, если просто первым проходом посчитать длину, а вторым дойти до середины, то количество обращений к списку не изменится.

Comment: @Qwertiy Формально ты прав, но тогда также формально можно скопировать на первом проходе элементы за линейное время и потом хоть за квадрат считай, по исходной коллеции ведь был только один проход. Если именно это имелось ввиду в задаче, то вариант с листом. Но имей ввиду, что, так как лист - динамический массив, то он будет иметь log(N) перевыделений памяти, то есть по идее элементы из списка сначала поучаствуют в проходе по списку, а потом в проходах по перевыделению памяти. Считается ли это за несклько проходов? я без понятия, это надо у автора задачи спрашивать

Comment: @Qwertiy и, кстати, с перевыделениями памяти в списке, проходов по элементам будет даже больше, чем в моем ответе, примерно на log(N/2). Это если считать все проходы, а не только по исходному списку

Comment: Поэтому в таких задачах обычно добавляют что-то в духе "с константным выделением памяти" и тогда копирования отпадают, поскольку зависят от объёма списка. Либо надо просто "с линейной асимптотикой", но это не то же самое, что "за один проход". И вообще, у меня ощущение, что за один проход без выделения памяти под копию сделать невозможно. А в 2 прохода можно не мудрить и делать тупой вариант с подсчётом размера. Вот и получается, что задача какая-то мутная. А на метод с быстрым указателем гораздо лучше подходит поиск цикла в бесконечной последовательности.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну мне гораздо проще, для моей головы, сделать 2 указателя, чем выделять память, потому я решил так. Это решение, в теории, и памяти меньше выделяет и по скорости должно быть быстрее, чем вариант со списком. Твое решение тоже неплохое, но согласись, что нельзя понять, что автор задачи имел ввиду под одним проходом, потому мое решение тоже имеет право на жизнь. А про циклы я конечно в курсе, мне с циклами на одном собеседовании попалась задача лет 7 назад - так и решил, бегунками :)

Comment: А я циклы первый раз по-другому решил, воспользовавшись ограничениями в задаче. А потом уже узнал с бегунками решение. Копировать смысла обычно нет - появляется только если идёт получение из внешнего источника или медленное вычисление. Так что я бы по умолчанию его предлагать не стал.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну если не копировать, тогда вариант с бегунками для задачи самый нормальный :)

Comment: `int n;
var p=head;
for (n=0; p!=null; ++n) p=p.next;
n /= 2; p=head;
for (var q=0; q<n; ++q) p=p.next;
return p.value;`

Comment: @Qwertiy твой вариант примерно в [полтора раза медленнее моего](https://i.imgur.com/nc4BlFZ.png)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95739/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-tym32167).